# Using the gsutil rm command

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-storage

I finally got around to using the gsutil rm command ...

I also noticed that the command shell allowed me to add up to 4 total instances ...

I have several buckets that have over 100gig of files that need deletion, so this was a great feature ...

However, my concern is with timing out ... it seemed that the first one I attempted to delete would cause Chrome to time out and lose the connection after 10 - 20 minutes ?

My question is ... can I start the deletion and close Chrome or does Chrome need to be active the entire time the bucket is being deleted ?

The last one was over 3 hours ... and I had to watch Chrome to make sure the connection would not be lost ... I had to reconnect several times over the 3 hours because it would randomly lose connection.

I also noticed when it first began it mentioned to use the -m parameter, but when I tried to add it, it seemed that the rm command was not compatible ?

Comment: Have you tried running it on a GCE VM in screen?

Comment: No ... I have finished deleting the buckets, but it took 3 days to delete 4 buckets ...

Comment: That is simply unacceptable ...

Comment: You could also set a 0 age lifecycle policy on the buckets and all the objects would be deleted in the background. Requiring deletion of all objects before deleting a bucket is an explicit design decision, because it's very error prone to allow deletion of a bucket that could have millions of objects in it.